# Clauses position: must a clause closely follow the noun it modifies?

Tags: clauses, restrictive-clauses

For both restrictive clauses and non-restrictive clauses, must they strictly follow the nouns they modify? Is there any exception of injecting adj/adv phrases between nouns and clauses?

I have the feeling that I did read sentences that contain clauses not closely following nouns, but I can't cite any valid examples.

**UPDATE:**

Actually I would like to discuss avoiding ambiguity when a complex sentence having several phrases and clauses. For example, in our discussion a sentence:

> I live in the house, and when I say house I mean more of a run down
>   shack, which is next to the river

after I added an ADJ phrase, the position of the clause "which is next to the river" will cause ambiguity of which noun it modifies, "the house" or "the redwood park":

> I live in the house in the redwood park, and when I say house I mean
>   more of a run down shack, which is next to the river

So what would be the rules for clause position in such a case?

Comment: What do you mean by *strictly*? And how close is *closely*?

Comment: Take the sentence, *" I live in the house that is next to the river.*" and add: *"I live in the house, and when I say house I mean more of a run down shack, that is next to the river.*"

Comment: @Jim closely means right after the noun. In your example, the *that* seems a pronoun rather than the word setting off a clause. In my understanding, a non-restrictive clause can only be set off by *which*.

Comment: Your question says, "for **both** restrictive and non-restrictive clauses."   You can easily replace *that* with *which* if you like.

Comment: @Jim thanks. If I modify your example a little bit, *I live in the house in the redwood park, and when I say house I mean more of a run down shack, which is next to the river.* Will it cause ambiguity that *which is next to the river* modifies *redwood park* but not *house*?

Comment: Yes it will cause some ambiguity

Comment: @Jim yeah, that's what I want to ask. In case there are adj phrases that contain nouns, how should we place clauses. For example, your example sentence.

Comment: Would edit your question to add the clarification of your question from the discussion? I think the example and the discussion about the ambiguity improves the question quite a bit and could prevent some close votes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Parentheses would be better than commas for setting off your clarification of "house"
2. This clarification should stay next to the word "house".
3. The default assumption is that clauses modify the most immediate noun, although this can be modified by context.
4. If you want two clause to modify the same noun, you can use "and" to make it clearer that you are doing so.

So:

> I live in the house (and when I say house I mean more of a run down shack) that is in the redwood park and next to the river.

Comment: I think hyphens would also be appropriate here

Answer (score 0):

I live in a house, more of a run down shack, which is next to the river in Redwood park.

How about this... Concise, and simple leaving the sentence without ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

> I live in the house in the redwood park, and when I say house I mean
>   more of a run down shack, which is next to the river.

If the house is next to the river, and the river runs through the redwood park:

> I live in a house which is next to the river in the redwood park, and when I say house I mean more of a rundown shack.

There's no *imperative* to move the clause other than the demands of clarity.

If the river is outside the bounds of the redwood park and the house is in the park:

> > I live next to the river in a house in the redwood park, and when I say house I mean more of a rundown shack.